# Use a Public Method of a Closed Form in MS Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to use a Public method from a form that happens to not be open at the time I'm trying to call it. I've found that:

```
Private Sub cmdPersonelEmail()

Forms!frmSwitchboard.cmdEmail_Click

EndSub
```

Works ONLY if the form frmSwitchboard is open at the time. Allegedly this is because Forms! is only a compilation (wrong word but cant remember the right one) of open forms. I was wondering if there was any way to call that Public method without the form being open.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do what you want by using the name of the form's code module to qualify the procedure call.

For example, my *Form7* includes a public sub, *SayHello*, which simply does ...

```vb
MsgBox "Hello " & CurrentUser
```

As you're aware, I can call that procedure when the form is open like this ...

```vb
Forms!Form7.SayHello
```

When the form is closed, I can still call the procedure like this ...

```vb
Form_Form7.SayHello
```

Although the form is not displayed, that approach does add it to the `Forms` collection and leave it there afterward.  So I would have to explicitly remove it.

```vb
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form7"
```

However, if that approach is acceptable for your purpose, it may not work, depending on the specific details of your procedure.  Mine is trivial, so no problem.

In actual practice, I prefer to move any procedure I want available when the form is closed to a standard module.

Yet another possibility is to open the form hidden --- the form is still accessible from the `Forms` collection when hidden.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to modify the codes in the form `frmSwitchboard.cmdEmail_Click` out to a module. But only works if the code does not access anything from the Form frmSwitchboard.

Sounds like the command button will send email. I would create a new module called `FormShared` and put a new Sub with arguments. Something like:

```
Sub SendEmail(sEmailAddress As String, sSubject As String, sBody As String)
    ' ... email codes from cmdEmail_Click without anything in the frmSwitchboard
End Sub
```

Move the Email portion of codes in cmdEmail_Click then modify it to call this SendEmail Sub. The modified cmdEmail_Click should prepare the arguments and pass them to SendEmail. This allows you to have it working with or without the form loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a form's member directly for the simple reason that a Form is actually a Class.

To be able to call a form's methods and properties it must be instantiated, ie it must be created and exist in memory.

As HansUp said, you can refer to the `Form_Form7.SayHello` directly, but in that case, Access will automatically create an instance of the form, meaning that whatever the form does, it may have unwanted side-effects. Furthermore, you will be responsible for closing that instantiated form.

On the other hand, you can view stand-alone VBA modules as some sort of global static objects that always exist and are always accessible (providing the member is defined as public).

So in your case, create a public method `SendEmail()` in a `Utils` module for instance and place all the code that currently resides in your `frmSwitchboard.cmdEmail_Click` in that method.
Then you can call `SendEmail` from all your forms.

Of course, one problem you will encounter is that you will certainly need to pass relevant information to `SendMail`, like an email address and maybe a message for instance, so you will probably need to add these parameters as well or fetch that data from somewhere else.

In the Utils module:

```
'Send the given message to the given recipient by email
Public Sub SendEmail(recipient As String, message as String)
    '... all your code currently in frmSwitchboard.cmdEmail_Click ...
End Sub
```

In your frmSwitchboard:

```
Private Sub cmdEmail_Click()
    Utils.SendEmail txtRecipient, txtMessage
End Sub
```

In your other forms:

```
Private Sub cmdPersonelEmail()
    Utils.SendEmail txtRecipient, txtMessage
End Sub
```